# How to stop Matlab crashing on (wrong) mex-file execution with CUDA functionality

Tags: matlab, cuda, crash, mex

I'm currently developing a mex-file with CUDA functionality to be used in MATLAB. When I'm doing something wrong (e.g. wrong pointers or something like that), MATLAB always crashes (windows prompts me to end, send the report for mathworks or attempt to continue). Is there a way to prevent this from happening? It's really annoying to develop like that but as you probably know yourself: Hardly anybody can write perfect code without 'trial and error'...
Thanks so far!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Matlab MEX file page](http://www.mathworks.com/support/tech-notes/1600/1605.html#gen_debugging),

> mex -g yourmexfile.c

if you're not doing this already.

Comment: This won't crash matlab? And how to attach a debugger? Sorry, but this is something new for me...

Comment: @Col To be sure, Matlab's memory manager is quite fragile, I've managed create really bizarre errors.  But many of them will be caught with this option.  Then run Matlab from the command line, from the debugger, as though you're debugging Matlab itself.

Comment: `-g` absolutely does not prevent Matlab from crashing due to mex errors. I'm surprised this is an accepted answer for the question. `-g` may indeed help find the problem, but suggesting the use of a debugger seems almost self-evident.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, there is no way to prevent Matlab from crashing on a mex bug.  But you may be able to attach a debugger to the Matlab process and step through the code.

I know for a fact that this works if your code is in an external dll that you load into Matlab.  I am not sure if this works with mex files.

Comment: Hm it's a pity that not, because this is quite often the case when developing things I haven't done yet :(

Answer (score 2):

You can **debug Matlab mexfiles including CUDA codes using Visual Studio and NVIDIA Nsight for Visual Studio** by the following procedure.

1. Define the system environmental variable **NSIGHT_CUDA_DEBUGGER** and set it to **1**.
2. Launch **Matlab**.
3. Launch NVIDIA **Nsight**. Right click on the Nsight Monitor icon on the taskbar and select **Options**. Select the CUDA tab. For the option **Use this Monitor for CUDA attach**, click the drop-down menu and select **True**.
4. Open your project in Visual Studio, set the breakpoints and compile it.
5. Go to **Tools** -> **Attach to Process**.
6. Click the drop-down menu next to the **Transport** field, and choose **Nsight GPU Debugger**.
7. Ensure that your host machine name is listed in the **Qualifier** field. 
   Note that this field is blank by default; you will have to manually select your machine name the first time this dialog is opened.
8. When you enter your computer's hostname in the Qualifier field, a list of available processes will appear in the dialog box. Processes that may be attached with CUDA usage will appear with CUDA listed in the Type column. If a process is grayed out and **CUDA** is listed in the **Type** column, it is already being debugged, so it is not attachable. Processes that are grayed out without **CUDA** in the **Type** column indicates that it has no **CUDA** usage in the process to be debugged. Processes that may be attached will appear normally, and the **Attach** button will be enabled.
9. Ensure that **Matlab** has **CUDA** in the Type column and select it.
10. From the **Matlab command line**, invoke the function defined in the CUDA mexfile. The execution will then stop at the first breakpoint and debugging could start.

Comment: It's a bit late for me, but thanks though for your answer. Hopefully it helps somebody when he lands on this question :)